# pandas sort values within each group after groupby sum and get the percentage of values after using cumsum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
amount    id    year_month
20        10    201903
20        10    201903
50        20    201903
10        20    201903
 5        30    201903
 5        40    201903
30        50    201904
10        60    201904
10        70    201904
 5        80    201904
```

I want to `groupby` `id` and `year_month` and get the `sum` of `amount` first,

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['id', 'year_month'], as_index=False)['amount'].sum()
```

then divide this sum of `amount` by the `amount` total of `year_month` `groupby`,

```
df_1['pct']=df_1['amount'].div(df_1.groupby('year_month')['amount'].transform('sum')).mul(100).round(2)

amount    id    year_month  pct
40        10    201903      36.36
60        20    201903      54.55
 5        30    201903      4.55
 5        40    201903      4.55
30        50    201904      54.55
10        60    201904      18.18
10        70    201904      18.18
 5        80    201904      9.09
```

I want to first sort `pct` within each `year_month` (e.g. `201903`) in descending order; then calculate the percentage of `id`s whose cum sum `pct` is less than or equal to `80` within each `year_month`; I am wondering whats the best way to do this and the result will look like (using `year_month` values as headers);

```
201903    201904
25%       50%
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Newskooler wondering how to do the calculation described in the last paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `groupby` by default sorting by grouping column, so `sort_values` should be omit. Then use custom lambda function with cumulative sum, compare by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) and for percentage of `True`s use `mean`, last convert `Series` to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose:

```
df_2 = (df_1.groupby('year_month')['pct']
            .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().le(80).mean())
            .mul(100)
            .to_frame(0)
            .T
            .astype(int))

print (df_2)
year_month  201903  201904
0               25      50
```